# Grouping data based on a field in R

Tags: r

I am using R to complete the following task. I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
Item Category Price
aaa      1    10.00
bbb      2    5.00
ccc      3    20.00
ddd      1    25.00
eee      3    5.00
fff      2    15.00
```

Is possible to group items by their categories and calculate some summary statistics (ex. average or total sum of the price)?

So essentially, I'm trying to create something like this:

```
Cateogry AveragePrice
    1    17.50
    2    10.00
    3    12.50
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `tapply`, `by`, `aggregate` are your friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that's a `data.table` (which will give you best performance and syntax):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(myDF) # where myDF is the original data.frame

DT[, list(AveragePrice = mean(Price),
          SumOfPrices = sum(Price)),
     by = Category]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was able to use this method to create the results that I wanted, but I'm having difficulty saving the results. I tried using save(DT, file="DT2") and write.table, but neither seem to be working. Any thoughts on how fix this?

Comment: Try `write.csv(DT, file="DT2", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)`. `save` will save the data in an internal binary format.

Comment: write.csv doesn't seem to be working either. When I opened my file, it was the original table that I inputted into R...

Comment: Right, because you didn't assign the output to anything. Call `summary <- DT[, list...]` and then `write.csv` the `summary` object

Answer (score 1):

To flesh out to @Roman Lustrik's suggestion, thus staying in base `R` for simplicity:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
 Category=c(1,2,3,1,3,2),
 Price= c(10,5,20,25,5,15)
 )
aggregate(df1,by=list(df1[,"Category"]),FUN=mean)
```

gives:

```
  Group.1 Category Price
1       1        1  17.5
2       2        2  10.0
3       3        3  12.5
```

or

```
tapply(df1[,"Price"], df1[,"Category"], mean)
```

gives:

```
   1    2    3 
17.5  10.0 12.5
```

(Note `df1[,"Price"]==df1$Price` so either style can be used). 
Personally I prefer the output from `aggregate()` and it's a bit faster, although on small datasets this is rather academic:

```
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark( aggregate(df1,by=list(df1[,"Category"]),FUN=mean) )
microbenchmark( tapply(df1[,"Price"], df1[,"Category"], mean) )
```

gives (simplified for clarity):

```
     min       lq    median       uq      max
2.233209 2.268719  2.311002 2.362932 4.018134
771.361 792.0915   807.2805 829.2435 1201.581
```

Finally, if you want output exactly like the example in your question:

```
a1 <- aggregate(df1,by=list(df1[,"Category"]),FUN=mean )
a1 <- a1[,-1] # remove 1st column
a1[,2] <- format(a1[,2],nsmall=2) # give 2 decimal places
colnames(a1)[2] <- "AveragePrice" # assign name to 2nd column
```

gives:

```
  Category AveragePrice
1        1        17.50
2        2        10.00
3        3        12.50
```